# Increment row number into the grid with Cygnite Framework pagination

Tags: php, pagination

I am using Cygnite PHP Framework and generated CRUD application using Cygnite CRUD generator. I changed pagination limit to 10 per page in my model class.

Now the problem is,

In the first page serial number is displaying 1-10 but when I am clicking on the next page, though records are different it is reseting the serial number back to 1-10 again. It should be (Second page) 11-20.

My view page:

```
<?php

if (count($this->records) > 0) {
    $i = 1;
    $rowType = null;
    foreach ($this->records as $key => $value) {

        $rowType = ($i % 2 == 0) ? 'even' : 'odd';
        ?>
      <tr class='<?php echo $rowType; ?>'>
          <td> <?php echo $i; ?></td>
           ..............
      </tr>

    }

}

?>

<div ><?php echo $this->links; ?> </div>
```

How to fix it ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope below code will help you.

Step1: Open /apps/views/user/index.view.php

Step 2: In this page inside top of the view page add below code to include.

```
use Cygnite\Common\UrlManager\Url; 
use Apps\Models\User; 

$user = new User;
```

Step 3: Now go inside if condition

```
if (count($this->records) > 0) {
```

replace $i with below code.

```
if (Url::segment(2) == '' || Url::segment(3) == '' || Url::segment(3) == 1 ) { 
    $i =1; 
} else { 
    $i = (Url::segment(3) - 1) * $user->perPage + 1; 
}
```

Step 4: That's all. Now run the application it will display serial number correctly into the grid.

Cheers!